# Flutter Slot Machine Game

Tags: flutter

I am trying to run flutter slot machine game.

This is from the package and it has three stop buttons to stop the animation.
The issue that I am having is I only want one start button. After delayed 5 secs, I want that to stop that animation without pressing any buttons.
That's what I am trying to do and couldn't figure it out.

Can someone pls help me?

This is the original flutter slot machine game package.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slot_machine/example

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: I only tried according to the package that I provided. Can't think of my own the way I want to. I am sorry.

Comment: You can give a try and include the snippet , You can find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create async method with `Future.delay`

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  onStart();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  onButtonTap(index: 0);
  onButtonTap(index: 1);
  onButtonTap(index: 2);
}),
```

More about [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Full widget

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late SlotMachineController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void onButtonTap({required int index}) {
    _controller.stop(reelIndex: index);
  }

  void onStart() {
    final index = Random().nextInt(20);
    _controller.start(hitRollItemIndex: index < 5 ? index : null);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SlotMachine(
              rollItems: [
                RollItem(index: 0, child: Text("X")),
                RollItem(index: 1, child: Text("Y")),
                RollItem(index: 2, child: Text("Z")),
              ],
              onCreated: (controller) {
                _controller = controller;
              },
              onFinished: (resultIndexes) {
                print('Result: $resultIndexes');
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
              child: TextButton(
                  child: Text('START'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    onStart();
                    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
                    onButtonTap(index: 0);
                    onButtonTap(index: 1);
                    onButtonTap(index: 2);
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: play with `Duration(seconds: 1)`